# Returning JsonResult results in 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm using jQuery's getJSON function to return a `JsonResult` from my controller.

### jQuery

```
$.getJSON("/Test/GetJsonWFA", null, function (data) {
    $(data).each(function () {
        alert("call succeeded");
        //alert(data);
    });
});
```

### controller

```
public JsonResult GetJsonWFA() 
{
    List<WorkFlowAssignment> listWFAs = new List<WorkFlowAssignment>();

    listWFAs.Add(new WorkFlowAssignment() 
    { 
        ID = 1, 
        WorkFlowName = "WorkFlowName1" 
    });

    listWFAs.Add(new WorkFlowAssignment() 
    { 
        ID = 2, 
        WorkFlowName = "WorkFlowName2" 
    });

    return Json(listWFAs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'm getting the following error: **500 Internal Server Error**.

If I replace the **WorkFlowAssignment** in **GetJsonWFA** with a trivial class everything works.

It seems to be related to the type of object in the list.

The **WorkFlowAssignment** class has many properties and methods.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error - would suggest that the `GetJsonWFA` function is failing - have you tried stepping through the function?

Comment: Fire up Chrome's developer tools and look at the 500 contents when it occurs. That should include a stack trace.

Comment: @ipr101 - the function works fine when stepping through - it seems like the method fails when trying to massage the list to return the JsonResult.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect that your `WorkFlowAssignment` model has some circular references which cannot be JSON serialized. I would recommend you to use a view model and break any possible circular references. Another advantage of using a view model is that you will send to the client only the properties it actually needs in order to do the processing. You don't need to transfer over the wire some complex stuff that the client will never need. So for example if everything that your client needs is the `ID` and the `WorkFlowName` do this:

```
public ActionResult GetJsonWFA() {
    List<WorkFlowAssignment> listWFAs = ... 

    var viewModel = listWFAs.Select(x => new {
        ID = x.ID,
        WorkFlowName = x.WorkFlowName
    });
    return Json(viewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and on the client:

```
$.getJSON("/Test/GetJsonWFA", null, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        alert('ID = ' + item.ID + ', WorkFlowName = ' + item.WorkFlowName);
    });
});
```

Also you should use debugging tools such as FireBug or Developer Toolbar to inspect the AJAX request that your browser sends and analyze the server response for eventual errors. When an AJAX request fails your first reaction as a developer should be to launch your debugging tool and see exactly what request/response is being sent.

Comment: Thanks Darin - that's where I saw the 500 Server Error - in the XHR tab of Firebug. But I get your point about the view model and will give that a try.

Comment: Thanks @Darin - adjusted the view model objects to make them simpler and it worked like a charm.