# ASP MVC vs jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I know there are several same issues available on this site but I couldn't figure it out even with their solution offers. I am trying to implement jQuery UI Autocomplete feature for getting a search function.

My controller is:

```
    public JsonResult search(int maxRows, string name_startsWith)
    {
        DataContext db = new DataContext();
        var result = (from p in db.Users where p.UserName.Contains(name_startsWith) || p.FirstName.Contains(name_startsWith) || p.LastName.Contains(name_startsWith) orderby p.LastName select p).Distinct().Take(maxRows).ToList();
        return Json(result);
    }
```

My View is:

```
    $("#search").catcomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/h/search",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                maxRows: 15,
                name_startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.UserName,
                        value: item.UserId,
                        categoty: "People"
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

So, as you may understand; I am trying to implement the category version. I am worrying about the value item. I am using Guid as UserId.

Thanks in advance for your kind helps.

**EDIT**

I made some progress by changing the control and view as below.

Control:

```
[HttpPost]    
public JsonResult search(int maxRows, string name_startsWith)
    {
        DataContext db = new DataContext();
        var result = new List<User>(); 
        result = (from p in db.Users where p.UserName.Contains(name_startsWith) || p.FirstName.Contains(name_startsWith) || p.LastName.Contains(name_startsWith) orderby p.LastName select p).Take(maxRows).ToList();
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View:

```
    $("#search").catcomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                url: '@Url.Action("search", "h")',
                data: { maxRows: 15, name_startsWith: request.term },
                complete: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.UserName,
                            category: 'People'
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Now the problem is:
When expecting the "success" behavior: it doesn't work regularly.
But when I choose "complete" behavior: now it always fires but without value?

Controller seems posting the value[count=1] but json is not receiving it!?

**SOLVED**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult search(int maxRows, string name_startsWith)
    {
        DataContext db = new DataContext();
        var result = new List<User>(); 
        result = (from p in db.Users where p.UserName.Contains(name_startsWith) || p.FirstName.Contains(name_startsWith) || p.LastName.Contains(name_startsWith) orderby p.LastName select p).Take(maxRows).ToList();
        var viewModel = result.Select(x => new
        {
            value = x.UserName,
            label = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName,
            category = "People"
        });
        return Json(viewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I solved the issue by packing the necesessary items in a viewModel before sending. I think something uncompaitable in the model was causing this conflict(500 Internal Server Error) with the json. (Solution found on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8027027/1062284 Thanks Darin! )

Comment: I am also trying to give label, value and category names hardcoded but it is not working in this case also. label: "Test",
value: "2",
categoty: "People". But when I try to give an array as source; it is working without any problem.

Comment: you can remove the `var result = new List<User>();` and replace it witl `List<User> result;` as you are creating a new instance in vain.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use FireBug in Firefox to put a breakpoint in the complete event and check what data you receive from the controller.

The success behavior only works when you get a HTTP 200 result and not when the server returns an error.

If you do not find the answer using the Javascript debugger and/or the Net tab in Firebug you can put the response from the http call to your question and maybe I can see the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but couldn't reach because the result was an empty object. Ayhow I found the proper solution atlast:) Thank you anyway